# Pandas concat only beside certain column values

Tags: pandas

I have a  100 row dataframe with a column "genres" containing either "Romance" or "Fantasy". I have another dataframe with 50 values. How do I horizontally concatenate these values only beside cells containing "Romance"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly mean at the moment, but aren't you simply searching for a merge function?

Comment: But I don't have any identical columns. How do I merge only where a column cell contains a specific value?

Comment: Could you share your data or simply take a screenshot? That might make it easier for further answers

Comment: You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) link as guidance on how to provide some data.

Comment: @Kylian I'm not sure I have time for that now. Could you point out exactly what you don't understand in my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous, you should provide an example of input/output. However, if I understand correctly, you can add values only in rows matching Romance (provided there are 50 of these rows) by using `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['genres'].eq('Romance'), 'new_column'] = other_df['col'].values
```

Comment: I know sorry about that. Your suggestion is almost working. My other dataframe 'Ratings' contains only one column of 50 string values. It is currently displaying NaN values when joined.

Comment: Use `other_df['col'].values`